# Extract rows using multiple conditions related to the order of occurrence of zero and one in R rule()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sample dataset that I would like to extract based on few conditions related to 0 and 1. this is the sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61), var=c("X1", "X2","X3", "X4", "X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10","X1", "X2","X3", "X4", "X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10"), 
                 zero=c(0,0,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,0), pos=c(NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA))
```

| ID | var | zero | pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | X1 | 0 | NA |
| 60 | X2 | 0 | NA |
| 60 | X3 | NA | 1 |
| 60 | X4 | NA | 1 |
| 60 | X5 | NA | NA |
| 60 | X6 | 0 | NA |
| 60 | X7 | NA | 1 |
| 60 | X8 | 0 | NA |
| 60 | X9 | NA | 1 |
| 60 | X10 | NA | NA |
| 61 | X1 | NA | 1 |

In each ID (60,61), I wanted to extract rows based on variables in columns name 'zero' and 'pos'. the first condition is, I want to extract rows that have a first occurrence of 1 and a last occurrence of 1. secondly, I want to extract row that have zero before the first occurrence of 1. Thirdly, I want to extract row that zero occur after the first occurance of 1. Lastly, I want to extract the last row with either 0 or 1.

Thus, the resulting table would look like this.

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(60,60,60,60,61,61,61,61), var=c("X2","X3","X6","X9","X1", "X4","X9","X10"), 
                 zero=c(0,NA,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0), pos=c(NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA))
```

| ID | var | zero | pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | X2 | 0 | NA |
| 60 | X3 | NA | 1 |
| 60 | X6 | 0 | NA |
| 60 | X9 | NA | 1 |
| 61 | X1 | NA | 1 |
| 61 | X4 | 0 | NA |
| 61 | X9 | NA | 1 |
| 61 | X10 | 0 | NA |

I tried with rle() and match but I did not succeed.
Please if anyone is familiar with extracting data like this. I would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your statement is confusing, you have a column called zero and you are talking about zero the value 0. Cnat tell when you mean the column vs the number

Comment: @onyambu sorry for the confusing statement. I wanted to extract rows based on conditions of value in columns 'zero' and 'pos'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a small function that reflects your four conditions, and then apply that function by group

```
f <- function(z,p) {
  p1 = which(p==1)
  z0 = which(z==0)
  c1 = c(p1[1],p1[length(p1)])
  c2 = ifelse(z[p1[1]-1]==0, as.integer(p1[1]-1),as.integer(NA))
  c3 = min(z0[which(z0>p1[1])], na.rm=T)
  c4 = max(p1,z0, na.rm=T)
  unique(c(c1,c2,c3,c4))
}
```

Now, apply that function by group

```
libary(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% f(zero,pos))
```

Output:

```
     ID var    zero   pos
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    60 X2        0    NA
2    60 X3       NA     1
3    60 X6        0    NA
4    60 X9       NA     1
5    61 X1       NA     1
6    61 X4        0    NA
7    61 X9       NA     1
8    61 X10       0    NA
```

Or, using data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[f(zero,pos)], by=ID]
```

Output:

```
      ID    var  zero   pos
   <num> <char> <num> <num>
1:    60     X3    NA     1
2:    60     X9    NA     1
3:    60     X2     0    NA
4:    60     X6     0    NA
5:    61     X1    NA     1
6:    61     X9    NA     1
7:    61     X4     0    NA
8:    61    X10     0    NA
```

Comment: Thank you! it works well. although because of my mistake. I did not clarify condition clearly. What if I wanted to include a row that have '0' in column "zero" after the occurrence of first'1' in column "pos". and this '0' could be after NA. so row #6 of df would have been included

Comment: Condition 3 could be adjusted; see my edit